# Get image from server file system to android application?

Tags: java, php, android, html

I'm trying to retrieve image file from my local server.

Here is my (very simple) php request :

get_image.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/*");

$images_folder = "uploads/";
$image_name = $_GET['image_id'];

$image_url = $images_folder . $image_name;

if (!readfile($image_url))
    echo "Error loading file";
?>
```

If I run this in a browser :

draw_image.php

```
<img src="get_image.php?image_id=<?php echo $_POST["image_id"]?>" alt="Image"/>
```

I get my picture drawn.

Now, how to retrieve this image in android application ?
Here is my code for the moment :

```
public void         GetUserPicture() throws Exception,  NumberFormatException
{
    try
    {
        String str_image_id = Utils.FromStringToMd5(askme_user.GetLogin() + Utils.SALT);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.7/askme/draw_image.php");

        List<NameValuePair> php_question = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        php_question.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_id", str_image_id));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(php_question, "UTF-8"));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity res_entity = response.getEntity();

        Log.i(TAG, "Status line : " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (res_entity != null) Log.i(TAG, EntityUtils.toString(res_entity));
        if (res_entity != null) res_entity.consumeContent();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception");
    }
}
```

and here is the current log i'm receving from HttpResponse :

```
Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<img src="get_image.php?image_id=971c4623a86a4cbac2f1deffaf3c40" alt="Image"/>
```

I'm kind of stuck here, I don't know what to to next...

---

EDIT : Thanks to caner, here is my final code,

```
String url = "http://192.168.0.7/askme/get_image.php";
if (!url.endsWith("?"))
    url += "?";

String str_image_id = Utils.FromStringToMd5(askme_user.GetLogin() + Utils.SALT);

List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_id", str_image_id));

String str_params = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");

url += str_params;

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream is_image = response.getEntity().getContent();
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is_image, "user_picture");

return drawable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `HttpPost` to `HttpGet`

Answer (score 0):

```
       //declaration
    boolean net;
//imageUrl you specify
    String imageUrl="";
    imageUrl=?;

    //code
    net = isOnline();
     if (net == true) {
                    if (imageUrl != null)
                        try {

                            // where imageUrl is what you pulled out from the rss
                            // feed
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageUrl.getContent());
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                            // log exception here
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.e("...............................", "" + e1);
                            // log exception here
                        }
                }
    //method
    public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;

            // return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

        }
```